# How to get system info from a Windows system partition without booting it?

Tags: windows, disk-image, boot-partition, system-info

I have some disk/disk-images of previous Windows installations from different machines (some of them from machines I don't own any longer).

I'm trying to find out which machine these used to be in.
Mounting them I can find out usernames from `/Users/..` directories, which could give some hint, but always enough..

Question:
How can I find out system and hardware info from the Windows system drive data?
e.g: hostname, CPU etc.

I suppose these are stored on the disk somewhere, but the tools I know only works on a booted system.
Preferably I'd like to do this from Linux, but Windows tools could be also useful.

Answer (score 0):

You will find this information from the registry hives, located
in various folders under `%SystemRoot%`, which is `C:\Windows`.

The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive is located under
`%SystemRoot%\System32\Config\Software` and
contains information about hardware. Every branch under this
key is stored in a separate hive file.

The `HKEY_USERS` hive is located in `%SystemRoot%\Users`
and contains information about the user accounts.

More detailed information can be found by just examining the
contents of the above registry hives.

For documentation, you could start from :

- [hivexsh(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hivexsh) :
  Windows Registry hive shell on Linux
- Wikipedia
  [Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)
- Microsoft [Windows registry information for advanced users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/windows-registry-advanced-users)

(This answer is only intended as a very initial pointer,
and is by no means intended to serve as a forensics tutorial.)